# Questions from the freeCodeCamp "Positive and Negative Lookahead"

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking about this question from freeCodeCamp.
This is the link: [Regular Expressions: Positive and Negative Lookahead](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions/positive-and-negative-lookahead)

> **Challenge : Use lookaheads in the pwRegex to match passwords that are greater
> than 5 characters long, do not begin with numbers, and have two
> consecutive digits.**
>
> ```
>  let sampleWord = "astronaut";
>  let pwRegex =   // Change this line
>  result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
> ```

At first, the model answer the site is showing is;
**`/^\D(?=\w{5})(?=\w*\d{2})/;`**

**Here are my questions;**

1. Why isn't a comma after 5 necessary?
   The question says "greater than 5 characters long", so I think it should be {5,}, not {5}.
2. How can I make a *lookahead* to check for consecutive digits?
   I think that the part "(?=\w*\d{2})" is not good enough to check for consecutive digits.
   I tried the following codes on my chrome console,

   ```
   let mytest ="pass75";    
   let Regex = /^\D(?=\w{5,})(?=\w*\d{2})/;  //This is the site's model answer.
   Regex.test(mytest);　　　//=>True
   ```

   "7" and "5" are not consecutive digits but it says true so I think this model answer is not complete.
   What do you think? Is there anybody who can explain how to solve this questions?

Comment: "digit"  describes a numeric character. Thus *consecutive digits* within a string does not necessarily need to be equal to *consecutive number (values)*.

Answer (score 0):

I have got stuck too, solving this! Lookaheads are considered tricky. Yet, we can fragment down the constraints that are mentioned in the problem and then combine each of them to solve it wholly.

Well, now, to your questions:

1. The comma is necessary when you say "at least a number of", i.e., if I need to consider a pattern for at least 7 characters, it should be `{7,}`. And, yes, you are absolutely right! But, the challenge hadn't put test cases to check that case. They might be more concerned about the inner pattern than the number of characters.
2. Yeah! For consecutive digits, `\d{2}` ain't just enough. The digits are meant to be consecutive, but, not consecutive only, which means that we also have to consider the case when there could be "zero or more" digits before (but not in the beginning) or after the required 2 consecutive digits. So, you could consider adding a pattern for that: `\d*`

Hence, you can come up with a solution similar to this to solve the challenge: `/(?=\w{6,})(?=^[^0-9]+\d*\D*\d{2})/`

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, my understanding of this task was not to match two consecutive characters of the same digit, i.e. "22" or "33", but rather just two consecutive digits, i.e. "23" or "49". Thus, `\d{2}` would do the trick.

Was stuck on this exercise for a while myself!

Answer (score 0):

The regex can be written as `/(?=\w{6,})(?=\w*\d{2})/`
The two parenthesis for the 2 conditions mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```js
Challenge : Use lookaheads in the pwRegex to match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long, do not begin with numbers, and have two consecutive digits.

 let sampleWord = "astronaut";
 let pwRegex =   // Change this line
 result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
 
 // solution 
let sampleWord = "astronaut";
let pwRegex = /(?=\w{5,})(?=\D\w*\d{2})/;
 /* we put {5,} not 5. because in question they asked characters greater than 5,*/
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: It also works without the comma...

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*Fix the regex so that it checks for the names of Franklin Roosevelt or Eleanor Roosevelt in a case sensitive manner and it should make concessions for middle names.

Then fix the code so that the regex that you have created is checked against myString and either true or false is returned depending on whether the regex matches.*/
let myString = "Eleanor Roosevelt";
let myRegex = /False/; // Change this line
let result = false; // Change this line
// After passing the challenge experiment with myString and see how the grouping works

// solution => 

let myString = "Eleanor Roosevelt";
let myRegex = /(Franklin ([A-Z]\. )?|Eleanor ([A-Z]\. )?)Roosevelt/; 
let result = false;
resutl = myRegex.test(myString);
 //=> this should work
```

Comment: This is a solution to [another exercise](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions/check-for-mixed-grouping-of-characters). Why post it as answer here??

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it! Remember the match passwords that are **greater than (not >=)** 5 characters long.
Rest is quite self explained in the code.

```
let sampleWord = "astronaut";
let pwRegex = /(?=\w{6,})(?=.*\d{2,}.*)/; // Change this line
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the question in freeCodeCamp slightly modified.

> **Use lookaheads in the pwRegex to match passwords that are greater than
> 5 characters long, and have two consecutive digits.**
>
> ```
> let sampleWord = "astronaut";
> let pwRegex = /change/; // Change this line
> let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
> ```

And my answer is for this question:

**/(?=\w{5,})(?=\D+\d{2})/**

As you can see, I used comma after 5. And this answer passed all tests.

**Answer1:**

However, the answer you find uses **\w*** in the second part. Which means that alphanumerics can match zero or more characters. So, this provides the condition of 'greater than 5 characters long'.

**Answer 2:**

In this question, consecutive means 'one after another' like *38, 11, 40, 23* not *124, 3456*.